# How to make wpf DataGridRow selected color override bound background color of DataGridCell?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGridTemplateColumn that defines a TextBlock which has bound Background and Foreground properties.  This allows the colors to change based on the value of the bound property.  So far so good, except I want the default selected row color to override my bound background color.  How can I do this in xaml?

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Text">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}"
                       Background="{Binding Path=BackgroundColor}"
                       Foreground="{Binding Path=ForegroundColor}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Ultimately, it seems like I need to determine if the cell is in the selected row.  If so, use the default selected row background color else use the bound background color.  I am not sure how to aproach this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refrain from directly binding the `Background` to instead assign a [`Style`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.aspx) to the `TextBlock` which uses a [`DataTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx) on the selection (`{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}`) being `false` and only then sets the `Background` to the binding.

Comment: That is the perfect solution.  Thanks for seeing what I couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most elegant solution, but it's fairly simple...

Add a 'CurrentBackgroundColor' property to your Item (needs to implement property changed), which by default you set to the BackgroundColor. This is what you bind your Background to.

Add a two-way SelectedItem binding to your DataGrid to a property with the following logic:

```
public Item SelectedItem
{
  get
  {
    return selectedItem;
  }
  set
  {
    if (selectedItem != value)
    {
      if (selectedItem != null)
      {
        selectedItem.CurrentBackgroundColor = selectedItem.BackgroundColor;
      }

      selectedItem = value;

      if (selectedItem != null)
      {
        selectedItem.CurrentBackgroundColor = null;
      }

      RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
    }
  }
}
```

What this does is

- If there is a currently selected item, change its background back to its default value
- Updated selectedItem to the newly selected item
- Clear the CurrentBackgroundColor by setting it to null. This will allow the selection highlight to be shown

If you were after a more elegant solution I would look into EventTriggers

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I went down this road but was truly looking for a xaml solution.